# Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: - Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am new to angular2. I am trying to understand how to use multiple `<router-outlets>` in a particular template. I have gone though many QA here but couldn't resolve my error.

**router.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'one',
    pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
    path: 'two',
    component: ClassTwo, children: [
        {
            path: 'three',
            component: ClassThree,
            outlet: 'nameThree',
        },
        {
            path: 'four',
            component: ClassFour,
            outlet: 'nameFour'
        }
    ]
},];
```

**component1.html**

```
<h3>In One</h3>

<nav>
    <a routerLink="/two" class="dash-item">...Go to Two...</a>
    <a routerLink="/three" class="dash-item">... Go to THREE...</a>
    <a routerLink="/four" class="dash-item">...Go to FOUR...</a>
</nav>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>                   // Successfully loaded component2.html
<router-outlet name="nameThree" ></router-outlet> // Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'three'
<router-outlet name="nameFour" ></router-outlet>  // Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'three'
```

**component2.html**

```
<h3>In two</h3>
```

**component3.html**

```
<h3>In three</h3>
```

**component4.html**

```
<h3>In four</h3>
```

The below screenshot is my current output:
[image]

When I click *...Go to Two...* **In two** is printed.
But clicking on other two links gives me the error *Cannot match any routes*

Comment: router outlet is another ro and you have to handle them with navigator

Comment: How and where should I give that sir? @RomanC

Comment: I think it's in the [router](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Solved myself. Done some small structural changes also. Route from *Component1* to *Component2* is done by a single `<router-outlet>`. *Component2* to *Comonent3* and *Component4*  is done by multiple `<router-outlet  name= "xxxxx">` The resulting contents are :

**Component1.html**

```
<nav>
    <a routerLink="/two" class="dash-item">Go to 2</a>
</nav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**Component2.html**

```
 <a [routerLink]="['/two', {outlets: {'nameThree': ['three']}}]">In Two...Go to 3 ...       </a>
 <a [routerLink]="['/two', {outlets: {'nameFour': ['four']}}]">   In Two...Go to 4 ...</a>

 <router-outlet name="nameThree"></router-outlet>
 <router-outlet name="nameFour"></router-outlet>
```

The `'/two'` represents the parent component  and `['three']`and `['four']` represents the link to the respective children of  component2


. Component3.html and Component4.html are the same as in the question.

**router.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'one',
    pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
    path: 'two',
    component: ClassTwo,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'three',
            component: ClassThree,
            outlet: 'nameThree'
        },
        {
            path: 'four',
            component: ClassFour,
            outlet: 'nameFour'
        }
    ]
}];
```

Answer (score 11):

please modify your **router.module.ts** as:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'one',
    pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
    path: 'two',
    component: ClassTwo, children: [
        {
            path: 'three',
            component: ClassThree,
            outlet: 'nameThree',
        },
        {
            path: 'four',
            component: ClassFour,
            outlet: 'nameFour'
        },
        {
           path: '',
           redirectTo: 'two',
           pathMatch: 'full'
        }
    ]
},];
```

and in your **component1.html**

```
<h3>In One</h3>

<nav>
    <a routerLink="/two" class="dash-item">...Go to Two...</a>
    <a routerLink="/two/three" class="dash-item">... Go to THREE...</a>
    <a routerLink="/two/four" class="dash-item">...Go to FOUR...</a>
</nav>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>                   // Successfully loaded component2.html
<router-outlet name="nameThree" ></router-outlet> // Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'three'
<router-outlet name="nameFour" ></router-outlet>  // Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'three'
```