# uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: application

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I am very new to angular. I just created a small application in angular and the back end of this application is .net core API. I can run the application on localhost without any issues. I published the application on IIS on a development server. I can  reach the application by typing the URL on my local computer. when I run the application. I get the following error:

[image]

My code is very simple, on the click of the button, I am passing some date parameters to my API. Below is my HTML code:

```
  <button class="appBtn lineButton" (click) = "LoadData()" >
    Start Loading

  </button>
```

below is my .ts file code:

```
 LoadData() {

   let  startDate = new Date(this.projectform.value.startDate);
   let endDate = new Date(this.projectform.value.endDate);


           this.service.UploadRecLoadData(this.RecLoadData).subscribe((tempdata) => {

           });

       }


     }
```

my service is just calling the api:

```
UploadRecLoadData(recLoaddata: RecLoadDataTypeModel){

 return  this.http.get<string>(ROOT_URL + '/' + recLoaddata.startDate +'/' + recLoaddata.endDate , {responseType: 'text' as 'json'});
}
```

I don't have any code in my app-routing.module.ts. Below is the default code that it came with.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


const routes: Routes = [];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

any help will be be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't in the code you provided. You are writing wrong routing code somewhere else. Your problem is like this :
[Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: - Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43657030/error-cannot-match-any-routes-url-segment-angular-2)

Comment: I provided the app-routing.module.ts file above and I didnt write any code in that. where can I look for the wrong routing code. I didnt make changes to any other files except the one that i showed above